# a program in Fortran90

Tags: fortran90

I have  this code in fortran 90 I think the code does not have any problem,

```
    PROGRAM xfitexy
!   driver for routine fitexy
    USE nrtype
    USE nr
    USE ran_state, ONLY : ran_seed
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER(I4B), PARAMETER :: NPT=30
    REAL(SP) :: a,b,chi2,harvest,q,sa,sb,siga,sigb
    REAL(SP), DIMENSION(NPT) :: x,y,dx,dy,dz
    INTEGER(I4B) :: i
    call ran_seed(sequence=1411)
    dz(:)=0.0
    do i=1,NPT
        call ran1(harvest)
        dx(i)=0.1_sp+harvest
        call ran1(harvest)
        dy(i)=0.1_sp+harvest
        call gasdev(harvest)
        x(i)=10.0_sp+10.0_sp*harvest
        call gasdev(harvest)
        y(i)=2.0_sp*x(i)-5.0_sp+dy(i)*harvest
        call gasdev(harvest)
        x(i)=x(i)+dx(i)*harvest
    end do
    write(*,*) 'Values of a,b,siga,sigb,chi2,q:'
    write(*,*) 'Fit with x and y errors gives:'
    call fitexy(x,y,dx,dy,a,b,siga,sigb,chi2,q)
    write(*,'(1x,6f12.6)') a,b,siga,sigb,chi2,q
    write(*,*)
    write(*,*) 'Setting x errors to zero gives:'
    call fitexy(x,y,dz,dy,a,b,siga,sigb,chi2,q)
    write(*,'(1x,6f12.6)') a,b,siga,sigb,chi2,q
    write(*,*) '...to be compared with fit result:'
    call fit(x,y,a,b,siga,sigb,chi2,q,dy)

    sa=sqrt(siga**2+sigb**2*(a/b)**2)/b
    sb=sigb/b**2
    write(*,'(1x,6f12.6)') -a/b,1./b,sa,sb,chi2,q
    END PROGRAM xfitexy
```

When I compile it I get the following error:

```
USE nrtype; USE nrutil                                                                                      1                                                                                                           
    Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'nrtype.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

Could you please tell me how I can solve it
Thank you so much

Comment: What do you think the problem might be with the `use nrtype` statement? Do you know what `use` does, and do you understand when/why it fails? Have you looked up the `use` command?

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I am guessing you copied this program from some other source.  Don't get me wrong, emulation is a good way to start learning any code, because it causes learning mistakes like this.  The USE command instructs the compiler to look for another file called a module that contains multiples subprograms (functions or subroutines) which must be stored in the same file as the program being compiled.  The modules titled nrtype.f90, nr.f90 and ran_state.f90 must be in the same file as the xfitxy program so the compiler can transform them into nrtype.mod, nr.mod and ran_state.mod files to be compiled into a single program with the main program.